# Azure Web App docker container gets updated

Tags: docker, azure-webapps

I've installed an azure web app with a docker container from docker hub.
After some time, when i try to run the web app. it is re downloading the container from docker hub. The container size is around 400mb, thus it takes a while to start the web app.

Is there any setting to make the container persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognised, whenever it is getting updated on docker hub, the container will be refreshed.